# How to run parallel execution of job using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have metadata file in which job execution sequence number has given. I want to execute jobs according to sequence number. Suppose 2 jobs have sequence number 1, so they will execute parallel. After that number-2 sequence number job will execute.

Please help me to develop this.

metadata file:

this is the metadata file. Im_Xref_Prod_bridge & Im_Xref_Prod have the sequence number 1 so both the job should be run parallel.

[image: this is the metadata file. Im_Xref_Prod_bridge & Im_Xref_Prod have the sequence number 1 so both the job should be run parallel.]

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the threading module, with that you can run functions in parallel, here's a quick example:

```
import threading

def firstFunction():
    …
    …
    return …

def secondFunction():
    …
    …
    return …

def func1():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=firstFunction)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=secondFunction)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

def func2():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=firstFunction)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=secondFunction)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func1()
    func2()
```

Comment: how to select Master Job Name according to Execution sequence?